# How to get a list of logged in users in .NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

How can we get a list of online users in razor pages?

I want every user to be able to receive the list of online users after logging in
Must be with Microsoft Identity.
tnx

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following methods to store the online users:

1. Create an Online User table.

   After user login successfully, you can add him in the Online User table. When a user logout, remove his record from the Online User table. Then, he can query the online user table to get the list of the online users.
2. Add a customer property (such as OnlineStatus) in the Identity User table.

   You can refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to add custom user data to the Identity, when user login successfully, you can change its OnlineStatus from "offline" to "online", and after logout, you can change it back to "offline". Then, user could query the Identity User table, and filter the online users based on the OnlineStatus.